# SQL Query - INNER JOIN - WHERE vs AND

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, where-clause

I was practising SQL queries and my solution to a question was:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM customer C
INNER JOIN salesman S ON C.salesman_id = S.salesman_id
  AND S.commission > 0.12
  AND S.city <> C.city;
```

And the solution given to this question was:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM customer C  
INNER JOIN salesman S  ON C.salesman_id = S.salesman_id 
WHERE S.commission > .12 
  AND C.city <> S.city;
```

However there is no difference between the two outputs.

So I wanted to understand when should I use `WHERE` clause and `AND`clause with `INNER JOIN` ?

Will there be any performance differences between the two given queries?

Comment: There won't be any performance difference in both the queries. Its a matter of personal preference. I would like to keep the join predicates in `ON` condition and filters in `Where` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all between the two queries.  As a matter of convention, conditions between the two queries are often put in the `on` clause:

```
select C.*
from customer C inner join
     salesman S 
     on C.salesman_id = S.salesman_id and S.city <> C.city
where S.commission > 0.12;
```

Functionally, though, additional conditions can go in either the `on` clause or the `where` clause -- the results and performance should be the same.  Note:  This is not true of an outer join.  In that case, conditions should often go in the `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff's answer is correct, however, i'm a big advocate of putting the conditions that deal with the relation, ie. the (foreign) key that joins the tables, into the "on clause" and the rest into the where clause. that gives a nice separation of concerns -- especially when u have a compound key.

if u keep to that pattern and the table structure changes affecting the join condition u only have to change the on-clause and need not to worry about the where part.